# Python package for Microsoft Active Accessibility library?

Tags: python, windows, automation, accessibility

Is there a package for Microsoft Active Accessibility library other than

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyAA/2.0

which seems to have been abandoned (I can't seem to get the source code from sourceforge )and does not support Python 2.6.

Thanks.

Comment: actually, I found this:
http://ja.nishimotz.com/pyaa
which is very useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate to answer my own question, but here it is for those who are interested:

ja.nishimotz.com/pyaa

is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Since MSAA is, I believe, COM-based, you could just use [pywin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/)'s general purpose Python-to-COM interface to access anything in that package.  Could you please explain why this is not the case?  Thanks!

Comment: Because I don't think you can do the kinds of things that are described here:

   http://mindtrove.info/articles/gui-automation-with-pyaa/

at least, not easily. I'm particularly interested in the  NotifyOnOpen capabilities.

Thanks.

Comment: That link appears to be dead and some other related links.  Haven't dug very deep, but look at http://www.cs.unc.edu/Research/assist/doc/pyaa/, http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/bugs/760614, http://sourceforge.net/projects/uncassist/files/pyAA/ most of which seem to be live but not very detailed.